# Enumerating executable files in C

Tags: c, unix, directory, ansi-c

I am trying to enumerate only files with the execute (+x) bit set. My code seems to list all files. It also seems to enumerate directory and the above directory which I do not want. Example:

```
..
should_not_be_executable.sh
.
```

Is there a way to filter '..' and '.' without strstr()? Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int
main (void)
{
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *ep;

dp = opendir ("/tmp/hi");
if (dp != NULL)
{
  while (ep = readdir (dp))
  {
    struct stat sb;
    if ((stat(ep->d_name, &sb) >= 0) && (sb.st_mode > 0) && (S_IEXEC & sb.st_mode));
                    puts(ep->d_name);
      }
  (void) closedir (dp);
}
else
  perror ("Couldn't open the directory");
return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: don't think so. See [readdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/readdir.html)

Comment: OK -- but any idea why my code is showing non-executable files too?

Comment: You have a typo - a stray `;` at the end of your `if` line. This means the `if` has no body, and the `puts` line is being executed for every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Also, IIRC, `readdir` returns the entries in the directory, *not* full paths to the entries in the directory,  So I think you're going to have to concatenate together "/tmp/hi/" (or whatever directory you're reading) and `ep->d_name` before calling stat.

Comment: @AndrewMedico - you should make that an official answer since it's the reason for the OP's problem.

Comment: Perhaps using [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) would be much simpler, especially if you want to search an entire file tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ep->d_name` contains only relative pathname of the directory entry. So you should change the Current Working Directory to `/tmp/hi` before calling `stat(2)`

```
if (chdir("/bin") != 0)
{
    perror("chdir()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* ... */

if (stat(ep->d_name, &sb) == -1)
{
    perror("stat()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

As noted in the comments by @Andrew Medico, remove that extra `;` at the end of your `if` line to avoid unnecessary printing of that `puts()` line.

`readdir()` returns a `NULL` pointer when it reaches at the end of directory, so you should rewrite your while loop as follows in order to suppress a compiler warning:

```
while (NULL != (ep = readdir(dp)))
{
     /* loop */
}
```

In order to avoid printing `.` and `..`, use an `if` condition like this in the `while` body:

```
if ((strcmp(ep->d_name, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(ep->d_name, "..") == 0))
    continue;

if ((stat(ep->d_name, &sb) >= 0) && (sb.st_mode > 0) && (S_IEXEC & sb.st_mode))
    if (!S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode))
            puts(ep->d_name);
```

Similarly, you can use `S_ISDIR(m)` macro to find out if the current entry is a directory and choose to not printing it.